# Tic Tac Toe doesn't flow into the required function

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why my X's and O'x aren't showing up. Here's how it's supposed to go:

function `playerMoved()` - player clicked a button, depending on whos turn it was the text changes. Inside of player moved we have a function called `changeText()`. 
It's supposed to determine if it was X's or O's click, and change the `innerHTML` to an x or an o. It's not getting into the `changeText()` method at all. It doesn't go there. I put a few alerts in the code so I know where I'm at, and it never gets to the `changeText()` function.

Also I have to turn this in at midnight and I haven't worked on the style stuff yet, so If you're bored and have any other suggestions for what I might need to do to get this all working, please let me know.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Heather M Smith
CSIS 1430 
7-23-2017
Tic Tac Toe
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <style>

            body, html
            {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
            } 
           

            h1
            {
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 75px;
                font-family: cursive;
            }
            
            #player
            {
                z-index: 5;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 50px;
                font-family: cursive;
                
            }
            
            .Table
            {
                display: table; 
                position: relative;
                margin: auto;
                width: 30%;
                height: 30%;
                margin-bottom: 25px;

            }
            
            .Row
            {
                display: table-row;
            }
            
            
            .Cell
            {
                display: table-cell;
                border: 2px solid black;
                height: 100px;
                width: 100px;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }



        </style>

        <script>
            
            var player = "X"; //switches between X and O
            var firstPlayer; //Whoever plays first in a new game
            var player1name; //a name
            var player2name; //a name
            var currentPlayer; //Current players name (whoever is taking the turn)
            var scoreX;
            var scoreO;
            var winner;
            var clickedArray;
            var winsArray = [7, 56, 448, 73, 146, 292, 273, 84];
            var clicksCount;
            
            
            function start() 
            {
                //alert("start");
                player1name = prompt("Enter First Player's Name", "");
                player2name = prompt("Enter Second Player's Name", "");
                currentPlayer = player1name;
                document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = currentPlayer + " choose a square.";

            }


            function startNewGame() 
            {

                alert("start new game");

                winner = "";
                scoreO = 0;
                scoreX = 0;

                //reset all clicked squares
                for (i = 0; i < clickedArray.length; i++)
                {
                    clickedArray[i].innerHTML = "";
                }

                //document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "Heather"

                //change who goes first
                if (firstPlayer === player1name)
                {
                    firstPlayer = player2name;

                } else
                {
                    firstPlayer = player1name;
                }
                
                document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = currentPlayer + " choose a square.";


            }
            
            
            function changePlayer() {
                alert("changed Player: " + player);
                if (player === "X") 
                {
                    player = "O";
                } 
                else
                {
                    player = "X";
                }
                document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = currentPlayer + " choose a sqquare.";
            }
            
            
            function playerMoved(id, value)
            {
               // alert("playerMoved: " + player + ": " + value);
               alert(id);
                if (id.innerHTML === " ")//check if square has been played
                {
                    changeText(id);
                    updateScore(value);
                    switchPlayer();
                    //check for winner
                    if (player === "X")
                    {
                        check4winner(scoreX);
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        check4winner(scoreO);
                    }

                    //Was there a winner?
                    if (winner !== "") {
                        startNewGame();
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        changePlayer();
                    }
                }
            }


            function updateScore(value) {
                //alert("Update Score for " + player);
                if (player === "X") {
                    scoreX = scoreX + value;
                } else {
                    scoreO = scoreO + value;
                }
                alert("PlayerX Score: " + scoreX + " PlayerO Score: " + scoreO);
            }


            function switchPlayer() { //Switches the current players name and displays the name in player h2 heading
                //switches Player Prompt
                if (currentPlayer === player1name) 
                {
                    currentPlayer = player2name;
                } 
                else
                {
                    currentPlayer = player1name;
                }
                //redisplay current player in h2 heading
                document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = currentPlayer + " choose a square.";
            }


            function check4winner(score){
                //alert("checking for winner" + score);
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < winsArray.length; i++)
                {

                    if ((winsArray[i] & score) === winsArray[i])
                    {
                        winner = player;
                        alert(winner + " Won!");
                        startNewGame();
                        i = 99; //breaks out of for loop

                    }
                }
            }


            function changeText(id) 
            {
                //storing ids of clicked div to reset later
                clickedArray[clicksCount] = id;
                clicksCount = clicksCount + 1;

                //alert("clicks: " + clickedArray[clicksCount]);

                if (player === "X") 
                {
                    alert("X should show up now");
                    id.innerHTML = "X";
                } 
                else
                {
                    alert("X should show up now");
                    id.innerHTML = "O";
                    
                }
            }




        </script>
        <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    
    
    <body onload="start()">
            
        <!--HEADING AND PLAYER NAME-->
        <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
        
        <!--DISPLAY NAME OF CURRENT PLAYER ON THEIR MOVE-->
        <h2 id="player"></h2>

        <!--TABLE-->
        <div class="Table">

            <!--FIRST ROW-->
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="Cell" id="1" onclick="playerMoved(this, 1)"></div>
                <div class="Cell" id="2" onclick="playerMoved(this, 2)"></div>
                <div class="Cell" id="3" onclick="playerMoved(this, 4)"></div>    
            </div>

            <!--SECOND ROW-->
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="Cell" id="4" onclick="playerMoved(this, 8)"></div>
                <div class="Cell" id="5" onclick="playerMoved(this, 16)"></div>
                <div class="Cell" id="6" onclick="playerMoved(this, 32)"></div>    
            </div>

            <!--THIRD ROW-->
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="Cell" id="7" onclick="playerMoved(this, 64)"></div>
                <div class="Cell" id="8" onclick="playerMoved(this, 128)"></div>
                <div class="Cell" id="9" onclick="playerMoved(this, 256)"></div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few mistakes in your code, `if (id.innerHTML === " ")` you need to equate it against `""`so it becomes `if (id.innerHTML === "")`. Then you need to initialize your variables, otherwise they give undefined values and you will get error referencing them. This seems to work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Heather M Smith
CSIS 1430 
7-23-2017
Tic Tac Toe
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <style>

            body, html
            {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
            } 
           

            h1
            {
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 75px;
                font-family: cursive;
            }
            
            #player
            {
                z-index: 5;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 50px;
                font-family: cursive;
                
            }
            
            .Table
            {
                display: table; 
                position: relative;
                margin: auto;
                width: 30%;
                height: 30%;
                margin-bottom: 25px;

            }
            
            .Row
            {
                display: table-row;
            }
            
            
            .Cell
            {
                display: table-cell;
                border: 2px solid black;
                height: 100px;
                width: 100px;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }



        </style>

        <script>
            
            var player = "X"; //switches between X and O
            var firstPlayer; //Whoever plays first in a new game
            var player1name; //a name
            var player2name; //a name
            var currentPlayer; //Current players name (whoever is taking the turn)
            var scoreX=0;
            var scoreO=0;
            var winner;
            var clickedArray=[];
            var winsArray = [7, 56, 448, 73, 146, 292, 273, 84];
            var clicksCount=0;
            
            
            function start() 
            {
                //alert("start");
                player1name = prompt("Enter First Player's Name", "");
                player2name = prompt("Enter Second Player's Name", "");
                currentPlayer = player1name;
                document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = currentPlayer + " choose a square.";

            }


            function startNewGame() 
            {

                alert("start new game");

                winner = "";
                scoreO = 0;
                scoreX = 0;

                //reset all clicked squares
                for (i = 0; i < clickedArray.length; i++)
                {
                    clickedArray[i].innerHTML = "";
                }

                //document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "Heather"

                //change who goes first
                if (firstPlayer === player1name)
                {
                    firstPlayer = player2name;

                } else
                {
                    firstPlayer = player1name;
                }
                
                document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = currentPlayer + " choose a square.";


            }
            
            
            function changePlayer() {
                alert("changed Player: " + player);
                if (player === "X") 
                {
                    player = "O";
                } 
                else
                {
                    player = "X";
                }
                document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = currentPlayer + " choose a sqquare.";
            }
            
            
            function playerMoved(id, value)
            {
               // alert("playerMoved: " + player + ": " + value);

                if (id.innerHTML === "")//check if square has been played
                {
                    changeText(id);
                    updateScore(value);
                    switchPlayer();
                    //check for winner
                    if (player === "X")
                    {
                        check4winner(scoreX);
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        check4winner(scoreO);
                    }

                    //Was there a winner?
                    if (winner !== "") {
                        startNewGame();
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        changePlayer();
                    }
                }
            }


            function updateScore(value) {
                //alert("Update Score for " + player);
                if (player === "X") {
                    scoreX = scoreX + value;
                } else {
                    scoreO = scoreO + value;
                }
                alert("PlayerX Score: " + scoreX + " PlayerO Score: " + scoreO);
            }


            function switchPlayer() { //Switches the current players name and displays the name in player h2 heading
                //switches Player Prompt
                if (currentPlayer === player1name) 
                {
                    currentPlayer = player2name;
                } 
                else
                {
                    currentPlayer = player1name;
                }
                //redisplay current player in h2 heading
                document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = currentPlayer + " choose a square.";
            }


            function check4winner(score){
                //alert("checking for winner" + score);
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < winsArray.length; i++)
                {

                    if ((winsArray[i] & score) === winsArray[i])
                    {
                        winner = player;
                        alert(winner + " Won!");
                        startNewGame();
                        i = 99; //breaks out of for loop

                    }
                }
            }


            function changeText(id) 
            {
                //storing ids of clicked div to reset later
                clickedArray[clicksCount] = id;
                clicksCount = clicksCount + 1;

                //alert("clicks: " + clickedArray[clicksCount]);

                if (player === "X") 
                {
                    alert("X should show up now");
                    id.innerHTML = "X";
                } 
                else
                {
                    alert("X should show up now");
                    id.innerHTML = "O";
                    
                }
            }




        </script>
        <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    
    
    <body onload="start()">
            
        <!--HEADING AND PLAYER NAME-->
        <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
        
        <!--DISPLAY NAME OF CURRENT PLAYER ON THEIR MOVE-->
        <h2 id="player"></h2>

        <!--TABLE-->
        <div class="Table">

            <!--FIRST ROW-->
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="Cell" id="1" onclick="playerMoved(this, 1)"></div>
                <div class="Cell" id="2" onclick="playerMoved(this, 2)"></div>
                <div class="Cell" id="3" onclick="playerMoved(this, 4)"></div>    
            </div>

            <!--SECOND ROW-->
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="Cell" id="4" onclick="playerMoved(this, 8)"></div>
                <div class="Cell" id="5" onclick="playerMoved(this, 16)"></div>
                <div class="Cell" id="6" onclick="playerMoved(this, 32)"></div>    
            </div>

            <!--THIRD ROW-->
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="Cell" id="7" onclick="playerMoved(this, 64)"></div>
                <div class="Cell" id="8" onclick="playerMoved(this, 128)"></div>
                <div class="Cell" id="9" onclick="playerMoved(this, 256)"></div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```